# Source Model not found for design attribute

Tags: product, error, mysql, edit

I have looked at similar answers for this question and non seem relevant to me as I haven't incorrectly named anything.

I have downloaded a sql from my live site and imported it into my local wamp server.

Now, when I try to edit a product in the backend of Magento 1.6.1 I get this error.

```
Source model "catalog/entity_product_attribute_design_options_container" not found for attribute "options_container"
```

I've looked at my tables and it doesn't seem like anything is missing.

Could something of happened during the export/import of the sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error occurs not because of a database error but because of a code error.

The reason is that the file `Mage_Catalog_Model_Entity_Product_Attribute_Design_Options_Container` is missing. This is attached to an attribute via the database and when this attribute is loaded it will try to find this file.

Since this is a core Magento file I would suggest that you download a clean version of Magento 1.6.1 and test this out with your database.

Comment: but at the same time of downloading the sql I also downloaded the home directory. 
Editing/adding products works on the live site just fine. But after I download it, it doesn't.

Comment: @josephdrury Did you check for the mentioned file?

Comment: I found this file "Container.php0000644" in C:\wamp\www\test\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Entity\Product\Attribute\Design\Options

Comment: @josephdrury that seems to be the problem I guess when coping the naming has been messed up. If you rename it to simply `Container.php` it should work well

Comment: Wow, magic. Thanks very much! works! 
What do you mean by coping? Why did this happen ?

Comment: @josephdrury I guess when you downloaded the files from your live system something went wrong.